# Checkers Against The King

Tags: strategy, checkerboard, board-games

The king has invented a new game called *King's Checkers*. The rules are simple, it's exactly like regular Checkers, the only difference? The **king plays first** and all his pieces are **automatically "king"**, meaning they can move backwards.

Yes, *force capture* is **enforced** (if given the option to capture, a play must capture)

You and his daughter are in love, and the king has offered his daughter to whoever can outsmart him in this crazy game of strategy and intellect. Assuming the king plays perfectly; is it possible that you can win the fair maiden?

Comment: In your checkers rules, can normal pieces capture backwards?

Comment: @xnor Can they in normal Checkers? (No)

Comment: Maybe we should send these questions to Board and Card Games SE. This seems a board game variant rather than a board game-based puzzle.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code This is a puzzle asking if you can win with perfect play, board games (IMO) would probably DV that.

Comment: @warspyking Do you have any reason to believe this is possible?

Comment: @Kaine Believe what is possible? That you can win? I asked if it was possible, so it's entirely up to you to find out :D

Comment: I am asking abiut you motivation in asking the question; i am not asking for the answer. As it stands the question fits the definition of "too broad" despite its popularity.

Comment: @kaine How is the question too broad? There are literally 2 answers: it's possible, or it's not. In order to be correct you simply have to back it up.

Comment: Read the definition. If it requires a simular proof to regular checkers, a good answer would be unreasonably long to be appropriate for this site.

Comment: Ive not flagged it for closure; i figure you know what you are doing.  I just wanted to confirm you have a reason to believe the question can be answered.

Comment: I [proposed a policy](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2939/4551) to avoid disagreements like this.

Comment: @xnor I don't agree with that policy. Saying you don't know the answer can sometimes lead to DVs.

Comment: @warspyking That's the point. If there's something about the puzzle that may affect people's judgment of it, it's disingenuous to hide it.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too broad" because the answer is quite likely that you can't win, but confirming this is unlikely without a colossal computer search. Because the poster hid the fact that they don't know the answer, the likely lack of a puzzley solution was not apparent when the question was posted.

Answer (score 3):

An incomplete answer.

> I'd like to say you can't win because normal [checkers is a draw](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/computers-solve-checkers-its-a-draw/) and the king has a strict advantage. But, technically that's not true because the king is also required to make captures backwards, which could in theory be a disadvantage.

Comment: No better answer than this will ever be seen so you might as well accept it.